# Dictionary popping

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, tuples

I'm trying to pop they key if it is not in dictionary thisdict but I keep getting a key error

```
userList = [User(id='1', username='bob'), User(id='2', username='john')]
players = {}
players['1'] = 'bob'
players['4534509345ffgdfgd'] = 'caleb'

print(players)

for y in players.items():
    if y not in userList:
      players.pop(y)
      
print(players)
```

Caleb should be removed from players because he is not present in thisdict. How do I do this please? Player does have attribute username and id

Comment: Where is the User defined?

Comment: Trying to modify a data structure like a list or dictionary while iterating over it often causes problems.

Comment: `thisdict` is not a dictionary, it's a list. `y` is a string, but the elements of `thisdict` are `User` instances, so `y not in thisdict` will always be true.

Comment: If you're looking to filter out entries, why not [use `filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) and do it more obviously? One thing to note here is you're expecting to be able to match inclusion via two mismatched things, one a string, the other `User`. Are you actually trying to test vs. the `id` property of `User`?

Comment: Right.  A better plan is to create a NEW list that only includes the ones you want.

Comment: I made a mistake, `y` is a tuple. But it still won't be equal to a `User`.

Comment: Y is the key in players and thisdict is a list of tuple of Users string username and string id, can you please right the answer with filter @tadman

Comment: Look more closely at what [`items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) returns. Hint: It's not the key. Additionally, it *still* won't be comparable with `User` without additional work.

Comment: Maybe what you want is to convert `thisdict` into an *actual* `dict`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `User` objects have an attribute `username` that can be accessed and that you want to modify the `players` dictionary.

```
# Generating a set of acceptable names *once*
player_names = {player.username for player in thisdict}

filtered_players = {
  key: value 
  for key: value in players.items()
  if value.username in player_names
}
```

This generates a *new* dictionary and does not modify the original `players` dictionary.

Comment: Could also do this with `id` if required, very little in the way of changes needed.

Comment: I'm getting error value not defined, I'm using python 3.11, they do have attribute username

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner to do what you want :

```
{k:v for k,v in players.items() if v in thisdict.values()}
```

Comment: I edited the question also but thisdict doesnt have values its not a dict